# ajax request not working?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am sending ajax request to a php page on a button click. Here is my request being sent

```
$("#enteruser").on('click',function(){
console.log("entered here");
var name=$("#ename").val();
var email=$("#eemail").val();
var role=$("#erole").val();

var data={name: name, email:email, role:role};
var url='addemployee.php';

 $.ajax({
     url : url,
     data: data,
     type: 'POST',
     success: function(response)
     {
         if(response=="success")
             {
             $("#rmsg").text("Hello World");
             }
         else
             {

             }

     }
 });

});
```

My this line is not working and URL after returning back contains the values I sent. So If I resend request the request is not sent again due to url. If I put the following line

```
window.location="anotherpage.html"; in the success block the page is redirected to the that page. Then why the rmsg paragraph is not being written?
```

I am adding the form dynamically using the following code

```
$("#create").on('click',function(){
var htmc='<div class="testbox">\n\
    <h1>Create Employee</h1>\n\
      <form>\n\
          <hr>\n\
      <label id="icon" for="eemail"><i class="icon-envelope "></i></label>\n\
      <input type="text" name="eemail" id="eemail" placeholder="Email" required/>\n\
      <label id="icon" for="ename"><i class="icon-user"></i></label>\n\
      <input type="text" name="ename" id="ename" placeholder="Name" required/>\n\
      <label id="icon" for="erole"><i class="icon-road"></i></label>\n\
      <input type="text" name="erole" id="erole" placeholder="Role" required/>\n\
       <button id="enteruser" class="button">Enter</button>\n\
      </form>\n\
    </div>';
$("#view").html(htmc);
});

$(document).on("#enteruser",'click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("entered here");
var name=$("#ename").val();
var email=$("#eemail").val();
var role=$("#erole").val();

var data={name: name, email:email, role:role};
var url='addemployee.php';

 $.ajax({
     url : url,
     data: data,
     type: 'POST',
     success: function(response)
     {
         if(response=="success")
             {

             alert(response);
             $("#rmsg").text("Hello World");
             }
         else
             {

             }

     }
 });

});
```

Comment: if(response=="success") are you sure that php script echo string "success"? i see no problem with the ajax call itself, just alert(response)

Comment: Try using the debugger first to see that your request goes through. I only use Chrome where F12 will bring up the debugger. Have that open and select the network tab and press your button to trigger your request. Look at the result (if it is calling addemployee.php) click it and look at the header to see that data is added to the header. Also look at the response you get.

Comment: please post your php

Comment: In php I have just 2 lines. <?php
session_start();
echo 'success';

?>

Comment: @Programminglover: What does the debugger tell you ?

Comment: you could add the `complete` or `error` callback and check what is the response, sometimes `success` is not called

Comment: Nothing tells. Even I tried alert(response); No alert is shown

Comment: @Programminglover: You should at least see your call to addemployee with the data supplied in the header.! If not you are not triggering your button click function.

Answer (score 0):

One thing i like to do when troubleshooting HTTP calls is to view the actual network event in a debugging tool.

In Google Chrome, use `CTRL + SHIFT + I` to open up the debugging tools. Then click on the `Network` tab. In here, you may view the POST and Response and verify that your response is correct.

In MS IE, you can hit F12 to view the developer tools there

Answer (score 0):

You are not preventing default behaviour for a form. YOu should say to your app: "do nothing with the form and make it handled by js".
Also you are using a delegated function in the wrong way.

To do so change this:

```
$("#enteruser").on('click',function(){
console.log("entered here");
```

to this:

```
$("#enteruser").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
console.log("entered here");
```

all the other part of your code can remain as now if the form is in the dom from the beginning.

```
$(document).on('click',"#enteruser",function(e){
e.preventDefault();
console.log("entered here");
```

if the form is added to the page after it is loaded. YOu can also replace document with any element already in the page that is before the form in the dom structure

Comment: what do you get in that case? do you get any error?

Comment: if no console messages are shown your click function is not being called. Are you sure that the id of your button is correct. ? Maybe post all the related code ?

Comment: No its not working. Can it be another problem? I added the form dynamically on clicking a button. So once the form appears if I check the source of page the form code is not shown there.

Comment: then you have to use the third version of my code but please show the form html in the question please

Comment: Hi. I have added the code that I am using for adding the form

Comment: Then the third version of my code should work correctly

Comment: But the third version of your code is not working too..\

Comment: @LelioFaieta: shouldnt it be $(document).on('click','#enteruser',function(e) etc...  swap the click and id of button

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <html>
    <head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

    <input type="text" id="ename" />
    <input type="text" id="eemail" />
    <input type="text" id="erole" />
    <span id="rmsg"></span>

    <button id="enteruser">Button</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $("#enteruser").on('click',function(){

    console.log("entered here");
    var name=$("#ename").val();
    var email=$("#eemail").val();
    var role=$("#erole").val();

    var data={name: name, email:email, role:role};
    var url='addemployee.php';

     $.ajax({
         url : url, 
         data: data,
         type: 'POST',
         success: function(response)
         {
             if(response=="success")
                 {
                 $("#rmsg").text("Hello World");
                 }
             else
                 {

                 }

         }
     });
    });


    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

***PHP:***

```
<?php session_start(); echo 'success'; ?>
```

Comment: @Programminglover you have to find out the difference because you posted only ajax part. I post total working code so that you can find the difference.

Comment: That extra things are also in my code. So it should have the same problem as me.

Comment: @Programminglover I have tested my code in local server. it is working fine. you can just copy paste my code and try again.

Comment: But the problem is I am adding the form dynamically using the code I have added